# How to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}x/( \sqrt{1+3x}-1)$ using limit laws

Tags: calculus, limits

I have been looking over the limit laws and watching videos but I can't find a similar problem.  The question asks me to use limit laws to evaluate the limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+3x}-1}$$

I tried rationalizing the denominator but multiplied the top out instead of cancelling the $x$.

Comment: Multiply and divide by $\sqrt{1+3x}+1$.

Comment: Use Lhospital rule. Differentiate the top and bottom and then take limit again. The easiest way is just to use L hospital rule.(not just for this limit question but for many other limit question as well.)

Comment: i just started calc a week ago im in and in the hospital rule isnt in the chapter section so i assume im not supposed to know it yet

Comment: btw how do i phrase my limit like that?

Comment: You can read up on it though. It will may things a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you Multiply and divide by $\sqrt{1+3x}+1$ you get
$$
\frac{x (\sqrt{1+3x}+1)}{1+3x-1} = \frac{1}{3} (\sqrt{1+3x}+1),
$$
which tends to...

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+3x}-1}=\frac{x\left(\sqrt{1+3x}+1\right)}{\left(\sqrt{1+3x}-1\right)\left(\sqrt{1+3x}+1\right)}=\frac{\left(\sqrt{1+3x}+1\right)}{3x}=\frac{\sqrt{1+3x}+1}{3}$$

Then$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+3x}-1}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+3x}+1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac x{\sqrt{1+3x}-1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3x+1}+1}{\sqrt{3x+1}+1}=\frac{\color{red}x\left(\sqrt{3x+1}+1\right)}{3\color{red}x}=\ldots$$